# Twig variables not available within set context

Tags: inheritance, twig

I have the following Twig templates:

`test_base.html`

```
{% if language == 'sv' %}
    {% set website = 'exempel.se' %}
{% else %}
    {% set website = 'example.com' %}
{% endif %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

`test.html`

```
{% extends "test_base.html" %}
{% set link %}http://{{ website }}{% block campaign_link %}/campaign/{% endblock %}{% endset %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <a href="{{ link }}">Click here</a>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

`test_sv.html`

```
{% extends "test.html" %}
{% set language = 'sv' %}
{% block campaign_link %}/kampanj/{% endblock %}
```

---

When rendered the `test.html` becomes this:

```
<div>
    <a href="http:///campaign/">Click here</a>
</div>
```

And `test_sv.html` becomes this:

```
<div>
    <a href="http:///kampanj/">Click here</a>
</div>
```

So It is like the `{{ website }}` variable isn't available within the `set` context.

Am I doing something wrong, is this the desired behaviour or have I come across a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the set `link` block inside the block `content` as follow:

<kbd>test.html</kbd>

```
{% extends "test_base.html.twig" %}
  {% block content %}
    {% set link %}http://{{ website }}{% block campaign_link %}/campaign/{% endblock %}{% endset %}
       <div>
         <a href="{{ link }}">Click here</a>
      </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

So the output for `test.html` will be:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://example.com/campaign/">Click here</a>
</div>
```

And So the output for `test_sv.html` will be:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://exempel.se/kampanj/">Click here</a>
</div>
```

A working example [here in this twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/henus5)

Comment: Thanks for answering. The child template is executed before the parent, therefore variable from parent is not available in child template outside blocks.

That Twigfiddle site was new to me, and quite helpful so thanks for sharing.